# ShieldBuddy TC275 as a drop-in replacement for MEGA 2560?

Tags: atmega2560

I have an autonomous wall-following robot based on a Mega2560, that is just about maxed out in terms of memory usage and speed.  I'm starting to have weird intermittent failures with previously working code; a function will work fine in isolation (same hardware, but only the minimum required code to run just that one function), but not when used with the full program running, and other issues.

I ran across [this article](https://www.rs-online.com/designspark/bringing-multicore-to-the-arduino-world-with-shieldbuddy-tc275) about the ShieldBuddy TC275, which purports to be pin-compatible with the Due (which I believe is pin-compatible with the Mega 2560, but I can't use the Due due to 5V compatibility issues), and MUCH faster, even if only Core0 is used.

I realize it is quite costly relative to other Arduino projects, but that's not a factor here.  Anyone have experience with this board as a replacement for a Mega2560?

TIA,

Frank

Comment: If it was mostly-working on a 2560 this would be overkill (but entertaining overkill). Level-shifters eliminate 3.3/5V issues, though, or split processing between multiple boards, like using an Arm-based board for computational chores and one or more 5V Arduinos for IO. But the ShieldBuddy's base-level support looks solid--only question would be regarding third-party library support. I'll know more in a week ;)

Comment: Ah, would you keep us posted on your progress then?  I spent some time on the ShieldBuddy forum, and there appear to be some problems with 'free entry tool chain' licenses expiring. (https://aurduino.boards.net/thread/251/free-entry-chain-license-expired)

Comment: Oooo no; ok, I'll keep an eye out and see what can be figured out.